# Separate Partition for Ubuntu?

Tags: installation

I have Windows Vista installed on my C drive. I want to install Ubuntu on my home PC.

Do I require another partition or can I install ubuntu on the same C partition as my windows vista.

Please respond back.

Thanks,
Fahad Zia

Answer (score 2):

Have you started the installation procedure yet?

Shortly after choosing the language you want to install Ubuntu in you are asked if you either want to install Ubuntu next to Windows or want to substitute the existing OS. By taking the first option ubuntu will be installed into a new partition that will be set up.

You also can create your own partition (that is the third and last choice of the installation client) and install Ubuntu into that.

Either way you will not be able to install the system into the same partition as your Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to make a separate partition (ext.4) and a swap partition (max. 2giga)) before the installation.  Yo can do this with gparted  (simple google for this program - for free and in linux).  During the installation Ubuntu will recognise this partition.  Take care: answer that you will keep your Windows OS - so Ubuntu will not touch at all Windows.  Afterwards you boot in dual mode: choice between Ubuntu and Windows.